# How to calculate logarithm in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I need to calculate Log (base 10) and Log (base e – Naperian/Natural).

I am now assuming that Log (base 10) is:

```
double log10 ( double );
```

And am I correct to assume that Log (base e – Naperian/Natural) is just:

```
  double log ( double );
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: If you search for "log" or "log10" in the SDK docs in the Xcode Organizer, you will find the corresponding man pages for those functions. No need to post a question on SO to find out what they do.

Comment: will do that in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `man 3 log` for man page. In iOS 6 there is also [vecLib](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002498) which has logarithmic functions.